# Sugar with vegetable oil safe?

Tags: food-safety, oil, sugar, safety

During my move to a new home a 10lb bag of granulated pure cane sugar had some vegetable oil drip onto it. After 2 days when I observed that I took the sugar out of its paper bag and put it into a large zip-lock plastic bag that appears to be airtight. Is the sugar safe and for how long? How can I tell if it goes bad?

Comment: What do you mean by "goes bad?"  Is the sugar dry now, or is it moist with oil?

Comment: By "goes bad" I mean it would be potentially hazardous to eat. The sugar is dry I would guess, the part with oil got mixed in with the rest of the 10lbs of it when I put it in the plastic bag so it is hard to check that specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see a safety risk.  Oil can go rancid.  That is a quality issue, rather than a safety issue.  Moist sugar could potentially mold, I suppose.  If you see mold forming I would discard.  Otherwise, this seems like a low risk situation to me.

Comment: Thanks! I will be sure to watch out for those things. I appreciate your help.